# Access text of a TextInput upon onSubmitEnding

Tags: react-native

I simply want to call a function with the text of a TextInput once editing of the text is done. Something like below

```
<TextInput onSubmitEnding={(text) => submitText(text)}>
```

But obviously the text is not passed as argument to `onSubmitEnding`, . `onChangeText` has it. But I really want the text after the user is done editing. So whats the simplest means to do this,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1º `onSubmitEnding` is not a valid event, the correct one is `onSubmitEditing`.

2º You can get the input value using `event.nativeEvent.text`

Your code should look like this

```
<TextInput onSubmitEnding={(event) => this.submitText(event.nativeEvent.text)}>
```

Comment: Thanks. This suits my needs

Answer (score 3):

I'm not forcing you to certain pattern, but you should have your `TextInput`'s value in a state. Then:

```
...
this.state = {
  textInputValue: ''
}
...
submitText() {
  console.log(this.state.textInputValue)
}
...
<TextInput
  value={this.state.textInputValue}
  onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({textInputValue: text})}
  onSubmitEditing={() => this.submitText()} />
```

is completely valid. Here's a live example: https://rnplay.org/apps/wirurQ